# Styling the JavaScript prompt dialog in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, dialog, customization, prompt

Given that Chrome makes it so easy to customize the look and feel of so many browser components - such as scrollbars - I was wondering if there is also some Chrome styling magic that can be used to  beautify the barebones JavaScript prompt dialog.  Only Chrome is relevant here so I am not bothered by cross browser issues.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's a browser dialog, so no. Just make a modal dialog with HTML/CSS/JS and style that as much as you want.

Comment: I wish I could.  The dialog is being called up by a NicEdit plugin.  Making a jQuery UI dialog work in that context is liable to take more time than I can afford to set aside right now.

Comment: It might be hacky, but you could replace the `prompt` global with a custom function.

Comment: Yes, I can see what you mean.  Hacky yes, but a whole lot easier than trying to understand the nuances of DOM ContentEditable etc.